# Acer predator helios 300 ph315-51-78np SSD upgrade

Tags: linux, ssd, samsung-ssd

Before asking this question I have done research and did not find an appropriate answer.

My laptop model is Acer predator **helios 300 ph315-51-78np** with 16GB ram and 256GB SSD (with windows preinstalled on it). As far as I know, the max SSD capacity for this model is 512GB. So my question is:

I want to remove (rid of) this SSD with preinstalled windows on it, cause I cannot delete windows, and replace it with one 512GB Samsung SSD. Would it somehow hurt the system? Because graphic cards and other stuff installed exactly on the windows system. I am going to install Linux on the new 512GB SSD.

If the first option is not preferable, are there any other ways to solve this issue? My target is just to remove default 256GB Intel SSD and replace it with high-quality 512GB SSD like Samsung Evo or Crucial MX500, etc and install Linux on it.

**The perfect option is**: remove ***Intel default 256GB SSD*** and replace it with ***512GB SSD (Crucial/Samsung) + 1TB SSHD Seagate FireCuda***

Thanks everyone in advance for your answers!